# How to integrate address search into a React Leaflet map?

Tags: reactjs, leaflet, package.json

**Question**

I'm trying to create a React application using Leaflet, and I want to add a search bar that allows users to search for addresses. I've already tried some libraries like `react-leaflet-search` and `geocode search`, but they didn't work as expected. My project uses `React 18.2.0`, and I'm facing some dependency issues. I'm also using Leaflet for the map. Can someone help me with integrating address search into my React Leaflet map?

**Body**

I have a React application that uses Leaflet for map integration. To enable address search, I've used the `react-places-autocomplete` library. Here are the relevant code snippets from my application:

```json
{
  "dependencies": {
    "@emotion/react": "^11.11.0",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.11.0",
    "@fontsource/roboto": "^4.5.8",
    "@mui/icons-material": "^5.11.16",
    "@mui/material": "^5.13.4",
    "@mui/styled-engine-sc": "^5.12.0",
    "@mui/x-date-pickers": "^6.2.1",
    "@next/font": "13.1.2",
    "@react-symbols/icons": "^1.1.7",
    "cloudinary": "^1.37.0",
    "dayjs": "^1.11.7",
    "dexie": "^3.2.4",
    "dexie-react-hooks": "^1.1.3",
    "eslint": "^8.32.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "13.1.2",
    "formidable": "^2.1.1",
    "idb": "^7.1.1",
    "immer": "^9.0.19",
    "leaflet": "^1.9.4",
    "leaflet-defaulticon-compatibility": "^0.1.1",
    "neumorphism-ui": "^1.0.2",
    "next": "13.1.2",
    "node-fetch": "^3.3.1",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-animated-css": "^1.2.1",
    "react-confetti": "^6.1.0",
    "react-confetti-explosion": "^2.0.2",
    "react-detect-offline": "^2.4.5",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-error-boundary": "^4.0.10",
    "react-hook-form": "^7.43.9",
    "react-hook-form-mui": "^6.0.1",
    "react-icons-kit": "^2.0.0",
    "react-leaflet": "^4.2.1",
    "react-modal": "^3.16.1",
    "react-overlays": "^5.2.1",
    "react-places-autocomplete": "^7.3.0",
    "styled-components": "^5.3.11",
    "use-local-storage-state": "^18.1.2",
    "uuid": "^9.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@svgr/webpack": "^6.5.1",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^14.4.3",
    "eslint-plugin-jest": "^27.2.1",
    "jest": "^29.3.1",
    "jest-environment-jsdom": "^29.3.1"
  }
}
```

---

`Map.js`

```js
// Imports and dependencies
import { MapContainer as LeafletMap, Marker, Popup } from "react-leaflet";
import styled from "styled-components";
import * as L from "leaflet";
import "leaflet/dist/leaflet.css";
import "leaflet-defaulticon-compatibility/dist/leaflet-defaulticon-compatibility.css";
import "leaflet-defaulticon-compatibility";
import LocationMarker from "./LocationMarker";
import { Stack, Button } from "@mui/material";
import CustomTileLayer from "./CustomTileLayer";
import { useState } from "react";
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from "uuid";
import SearchBarMap from "./SearchBarMap";

// Leaflet Icon
const goldIcon = new L.Icon({
  iconUrl:
    "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pointhi/leaflet-color-markers/master/img/marker-icon-2x-gold.png",
  shadowUrl:
    "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet/0.7.7/images/marker-shadow.png",
  iconSize: [25, 41],
  iconAnchor: [12, 41],
  popupAnchor: [1, -34],
  shadowSize: [41, 41],
});

// Main component for the map
export default function MainMap({ markers }) {
  // ...

  // Function to handle the click on the "Return current position" button
  function handleReturnCurrentPosition() {
    console.log("I have clicked return button!!");
    const newCurrentPositionId = uuidv4();
    setReturnCurrentPosition(newCurrentPositionId);
    console.log(newCurrentPositionId);
  }

  // ...

  // Return the component with map, markers, etc.
  return (
    <Stack>
      <StyledMapContainer center={[50.123, 8.234]} zoom={12} scrollWheelZoom>
        {/* ... */}
      </StyledMapContainer>
      <Button onClick={handleReturnCurrentPosition}>
        Return current position
      </Button>
      <SearchBarMap />
    </Stack>
  );
}

// ...
```

---

`SearchBarMap.js`

```js
// Component for the search bar
export default function SearchBarMap() {
  // ...

  // Function to select an address from the suggestions
  async function handleSelect(address) {
    try {
      const results = await geocodeByAddress(address);
      const latLng = await getLatLng(results[0]);
      setCoordinates(latLng);
      console.log("Selected:", address);
      console.log("Coordinates:", coordinates);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error", error);
    }
  }

  // ...

  // Return the component with the search bar
  return (
    <PlacesAutocomplete
      value={address}
      onChange={handleAddressChange}
      onSelect={handleSelect}
    >
      {/* ... */}
    </PlacesAutocomplete>
  );
}

// Styled component for the MapContainer
const StyledMapContainer = styled(LeafletMap)`
  height: 30rem;
  width: 50rem;
  margin: 0 auto;
`;

// ...
```

In this code example, I've integrated `react-places-autocomplete` to enable address search. The `MainMap` component contains the Leaflet map, markers, and popups. The `SearchBarMap` component includes the search bar and utilizes the `geocodeByAddress` and `getLatLng` functions to convert the selected address into coordinates.

---

Since I've encountered several dependency issues with my React application, it would be great to find a solution that works well with `React 18.2.0` and doesn't cause any further conflicts. I prefer not to rely on Google Maps JavaScript API or other paid services for address search. I have already searched for OSM (OpenStreetMap)-based libraries, but haven't found a suitable solution yet.
Are there any other suggestions for React libraries or guides that could help me?
I'm looking for an alternative that aligns with my requirements and doesn't require the use of Google services.

Thank you in advance for your assistance!

Comment: did you get it working with React 16?